# Samsung 850 Evo SSD with Windows 10 randomly freezing and display settings issues

Tags: windows-10, freeze, display-settings

I've got a strange problem with my SSD. I've installed my system on it (windows 10) and it was working fine for some time (aside from occasional freezes at the start of a system). Now when I boot my PC, I can not access some of the things on my main C: drive (SSD) where Windows is installed. For example, when I right-click on the desktop and I choose display settings, a message pops up and tells me that there is no program associated with this task.

I can access files on my SSD - pictures etc...

I tried to change AHCI to IDE in BIOS, but then I couldn't boot up my PC due to drive being inaccessible.

One more thing - when I try to run some program installation from my other drive (HDD), it just freezes.

Any suggestions? I'm desperate.

Comment: It's possible that your other non SSD drive has stopped working and is causing your problems, have you tried disconnecting it? Also do you have Samsung Magician installed as that may highlight any issues with your SSD.

Comment: `I tried to change AHCI to IDE in BIOS, but then I couldn't boot up my PC due to drive being inaccessible.  That is what is supposed to happen. I you change the disk controller from normal AHCI to legacy mode and then boot windows which is configured to look for its files on an AHCI disk then it will not find its disk or files and boot will fail. Leave this on the AHCI setting.

Comment: It's less likely this is a hardware issue with the SSD and more an issue with the OS.  It does sound like there may be a mechanical or filesystem error with the mechanical HDD (check it's S.M.A.R.T data via CrystalDiskInfo, then issue the following in a terminal for the HDD's drive letter: `chkdsk /x /offlinescanandfix <driveletter>:`).  If neither shows an issue, disconnect it from the PC and see if the system hangs still exist.  The OS errors should be able to be corrected via the following: `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` then `sfc /scannow`.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this problem also exists in my Samsung SSD 850 EVO mSATA in a  Dell Precision M4800

I have been looking to solve this problem for two months. I had discovered that the problem was less frequent when the power supply was plugged. When the computer was operating only from battery, freezing occured almost instantly after loading the windows welcome message.

The cause is that EVO850 does not support Intel Rapid Storage LPM, and when the OS is requesting Low power operations, the system freezes.

There are some people saying that a solution is disabling AHCI from BIOS, working only under ATA compatibility mode. And it is true that this works, because ATA has no Low power management features. But the right thing to do is to disable the LPM management from Intel Rapid Storage.

There are two options to do this:

- The first one is to alter the windows registry, as explained here [enter link description here](http://www.ithacks.com/2012/10/14/fixing-an-ssd-freezing-on-windows-7/)
- The second is to disable it from the Intel Rapid Storage control panel (tab "Performance").Explained here: http://cs.mcgill.ca/~mxia3/2016/05/02/Fix-SSD-freezing-on-Windows-10/

To be sure that this works, just do both!!

And if you are worried about disabling LPM, just don't!! This is only useful for mechanical hard drives. SSD drives have a very reduced power consumption and do not really get any benefit from LPM.

Comment: Please quote at least the most important parts of the solution(s) you link to. If these pages disappear your answer will be hardly useful.

Comment: Intel RST only applies if you've configured the SSD as part of a RAID setup, otherwise, RST has no use (at least that I'm aware of).